# Insert data in another table through entity framework MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to save student's data in student table and their address in student details table i can't insert data in second table.

**Error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

**Student Model**

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**StudentDetails**

```
public partial class StudentDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public Student Students { get; set; }

    public StudentDetail StudentDetails { get; set; }

}
```

**DbSet**

```
public partial class SampleEntities : DbContext
{
    public SampleEntities()
        : base("name=SampleEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }


    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Basics.Models.Student> Students { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Basics.Models.StudentDetail> StudentDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
private SampleEntities db = new SampleEntities();
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(StudentViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Students.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.Students.Add(model.Students);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //The Newly created Id gets created and when saving that Id in anothr table the exception comes  
        model.StudentDetails.Id = model.Students.Id;
        //For Time Being in real time it won't be hard coded  
        model.StudentDetails.Address = "New Jersey";
        db.StudentDetails.Add(model.StudentDetails);
        db.SaveChanges(); 
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model.Students);
}
```

Comment: model.StudentDetails.Id = model.Students.Id; the newly created Id comes but its not going in new tables's Id.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have

```
public StudentDetail StudentDetails { get; set; }
```

in Student class and change Id for

```
public int StudentId { get; set; }
```

and then change Id in StudentDetail for also

```
public int StudentId { get; set; }
```

Like that Entity Framework will be able to join them in a 1 to 1 relationship. You'll have to add some primary keys/foreign keys depending on your needs.

Comment: Are columns name the issue,I have Id as PK in Student table and decorated it with KEY then too the same issue.

Comment: Did you add the StudentDetail property in the Student class?

Comment: Why to do that and it won't work as when Student class will run it will throw a exception stating StudentDetail not found.

Comment: Yes that is true. Maybe EF is picky with the Id name in this case?

Comment: Renamed Id to StudentId and cleaned the solution then too the same error StudentDetails is not a part of model for current context.